# Thymeleaf with Spring MVC + Swagger

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, swagger, swagger-ui

I would like to know how I can integrate these three technologies.
I am currently working on a web application build with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf template revolver for my web views. My web MVC+Thymeleaf configuration is completely XML free and here is the most relevant part for the web configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConfigWebMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
/**
 * Thymeleaf config - Spring will use Thymeleaf to render the HTML views
 * @return The Thymeleaf resolver
 */
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    LOGGER.info("CREATING TEMPLATE RESOLVER");
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix( environment.getProperty("web.template_prefix") );
    resolver.setSuffix( environment.getProperty("web.template_suffix") );
    resolver.setTemplateMode( environment.getProperty("web.template_style") );
    resolver.setCacheable(true);
    return resolver;
}

/**
 * Thymeleaf config - Thymeleaf will use templateEngine to understand 
 * Spring MVC, Spring Security dialects and th: tags
 * @return The Thymeleaf engine
 */
@Bean 
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    LOGGER.info("CREATING TEMPLATE ENGINE");
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setDialect( new SpringStandardDialect() );
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());     
    return engine;
}

/**
 * Thymeleaf config - Spring MVC will use thymeleafViewResolver to set the correct template resolver 
 * @return The Thymeleaf resolver
 */
@Bean 
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    LOGGER.info("CREATING TEMPLATE ENGINE RESOLVER");
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return resolver;
}
}
```

At this moment, I would like to add some rest controllers and its documentation made with swagger / swagger UI but I have no idea about the integration with thymeleaf. I know that is possible to integrate with Spring MVC and I have a working example WITHOUT thymeleaf.

It is not mandatory to use swagger but I am looking for a practical and visual-friendly documentation tool to integrate with these technologies.

Comment: are you trying to return xml parsed by Thymeleaf, or simple json/xml objects, if its the second there should be no problems

Comment: I suppose Swagger works with json in order to build the interface but I need to configure a kind of path or template such as /api-doc/index where all the generated api documentation will be available.

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps to integrate Swagger with thymeleaf and spring MVC

1- Add the required dependencies to your pom file

```
<!-- swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

2- Extend the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to addResourceHandlers

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public WebConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

3- Create the swagger config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.ant("/**")).build().apiInfo(apiInfo()).useDefaultResponseMessages(false);

    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("Application name", "API description", "API TOS", "Terms of service", new Contact("Hany Sakr", "website", "email"), "License of API", "API license URL", Collections.emptyList());
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

4-After running the app, access swagger using the following links

```
http://localhost:8080/{YourApplication}/v2/api-docs
http://localhost:8080/{YourApplication}/swagger-ui.html
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: I had same problem with Thymeleaf, Spring Boot, Spring Rest and MVC when working in Tandem. I was not able to get swagger-ui accessible. Solution provided above perfectly works. Thanks Hany Sakr

Comment: Thank you very much `addResourceHandlers` is really what we needed to override the Thymeleaf resolver.

Comment: Just one question. Why do I need the fileupload dependency?

Comment: Hi n00bst3r, I don't remember at that time the reason to use the file-upload depenency, but you can try without it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the [swagger documentation library for springmvc](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc)?

In a very minimal setup

In your pom file add the following dependency to the  swagger-springmvc library

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you're using gradle

`compile "com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:0.9.4"`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger //enable the library
public class ConfigWebMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
/**
 * Thymeleaf config - Spring will use Thymeleaf to render the HTML views
 * @return The Thymeleaf resolver
 */
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
// your config...
}
```

You can completely customize the plugin. More documentation is available at the [github repo](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc#swaggerspringmvcplugin-spring-java-configuration) and we're more than happy to answer any questions in the issues.

DISCLAIMER: I'm an author of the library.